# Don't prompt me to vote when I can't

Tags: feature-request, voting, login, auto-login

I just visited [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke), and Stack Exchange offered to log me in, so I did so (refreshing the page in the process). The page then told me that I should upvote the question and answers if I found them useful. I can't upvote them, because the question is locked. Since I can't actually vote, I shouldn't have been prompted.